# Could not start mining on my private chain

Tags: cloud, blockchain, ethereum, go-ethereum

I'm not able to mine on my private chain via geth console, get stuck in the following step.

```
    > miner.start()
    INFO [01-05|11:11:22] Updated mining threads                    threads=0
    INFO [01-05|11:11:22] Transaction pool price threshold updated price=18000000000 null
    > INFO [01-05|11:11:22] Starting mining operation 
    INFO [01-05|11:11:22] Commit new mining work                   number=1 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=482.122µs
```

Environment: AliCloud server with Ubantu X86_64; 1GB RAM  1 CPU Core.

here is genesis.json I used:

```
{
    "config": {
    "chainId": 201804,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0
},
"timestamp": "0x0",
"gasLimit": "0x888888888000000",
"difficulty": "0x400",
"coinbase": "0x9933333333333333333333333333333333333333",
"alloc": {}
}
```

create node1 with

```
   geth --datadir "node1/" init genesis.json`.
```

start node1 with

```
geth --identity "node1" --rpc --rpcport 8101 --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir "./node1" --port 31001 --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" --networkid 201804 console
```

In additional: The mining works fine with same configurations and commands in my MAC laptop. Maybe miner stuck in cloud server because lack of CPU core or RAM, but I'm not sure.

Could any one help on this?

Comment: Share your geth command parameters you used.

Comment: @GangadharKairi discription updated

Comment: This might be a bug https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2174, try deleting the datadir/.etash and start the miner again.

Comment: @GangadharKairi Thank you for the information. But I could not find any related file under datadir which is 'node1' in this scenario. `find ./node1 '*eta*'` it returns null.

Comment: @GangadharKairi After I upgrade cloud server to 2 Cores+4GB RAM. Miner is working fine. Thanks for all the kindly support!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try deleting the datadir/.etash and start the miner again.(
This might be a bug github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2174) or upgrade your cloud server resources.

Comment: datadir/.ethash is not enough for me. I have to blow the whole datadir/ away.